# Could not locate file 'mydatabase' for database 'mydatabase' in sys.database_files. The file either does not exist, or was dropped

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

`dbcc shrinkfile('mydatabase',113311)` fails with following error

Could not locate file 'mydatabase' for database 'mydatabase' in sys.database_files. The file either does not exist, or was dropped

Its failing once in while randomly. I have nightly task that executes `dbcc shrinkfile`. Works fine most of the time. There is no problem with logical file name etc...
my logical file name is 'mydatabase'. I have verified my logical name using below queries.

```
DBCC FILEHEADER (mydatabase)

select * from mydatabase.dbo.sysfiles 

Select * from master..sysaltfiles
```

This is really strange as i could't find any root cause. SQL 2008R2 SP2

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue in sql server 2012. Quick fix you can use file id instead of logical name to shrink the file. Secondly check what is the logical name in master_files and in database_files. I had different in master_files than in database_files. So you need to just run alter database to set again the logical name for the file and then it works just fine.

Answer (score 5):

```
dbcc shrinkfile('mydatabase',113311)
```

Note that 'mydatabase' should be logical name.

You can find the logical name from the file tab under data base properties window.

[image]
**Note**

- Verify the Logical Name and Database Same .Other wise it woud'nt work
- Here I Marked with red .the database name and Logicalname different.
- **So consider the Logical Name and execute  .Database->properites->File**

Answer (score 3):

I tried all of the above and still had the issue. Database was called clientdatabase and the log file clientdatabase_log.

I managed to resolve it by renaming the logical name of the log file:

```
USE [clientdatabase];
ALTER DATABASE clientdatabase MODIFY FILE 
(NAME = clientdatabase_log, NEWNAME = clientdatabase_log_1);
```

Running the script

```
USE [clientTdatawarehouse]
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (clientTDataWarehouse_log_1, 1024)
GO
```

Now worked.

I blogged about it here:

[https://hybriddbablog.com/answer-to-could-not-locate-file-xxx_log-for-database-xxx-in-sys-database_files/](https://hybriddbablog.com/answer-to-could-not-locate-file-xxx_log-for-database-xxx-in-sys-database_files)

Comment: Thank you for this!  I just ran across it myself and sure enough renaming it did the trick. In fact, renaming it to the very same name also does the trick!